# Is it possible to handle a query string on an img src url with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, google-analytics

I am working on a rails project where I handle sending out daily newsletters. I was looking into email analytics and think it would be great if I could do some basic stuff within my app such as just seeing if the messages get opened (And hopefully have a process to stop sending them if they never get opened).

The main method to do email analytics that I have seen used is to include a 1 pixel x 1 pixel image in the email with it's source url having a query string that identifies the particular piece of mail or batch of mail.

The question is how can I deal with this in rails?  I'm pretty new to this and it is my current understanding that the image just gets served from the asset pipeline.  Is it possible to override this with a route so I can catch it with a controller? If so how do I render back the image by itself as opposed to html with the image embedded?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not an answer to your question, I'd highly recommend outsourcing your email to someone like Mandrill or Sendgrid.  So much simpler and they provide exactly what you're looking for already.

That said you can do what you want by creating a route such as "/email-tracker.png" (could be anything really) and in the controller action do your analytics and then send back image data for a 1x1 png image.  See the `send_data` method for more info.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_data

Comment: Thanks! I think the send_data part is really what I was missing.  Outsourcing would be a decent option but its all been done in-house previously so we want to keep it that way.  On top of that it just seems easier to do it myself with several different newsletters that go out daily each pulling their template from a website with that days content.

Comment: I'd highly suggest looking into Mandrill.  12K emails/day free.  Suppose it all depends on the size of your lists, but shoving the newsletter over to them is easy.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

+1 to Philip Hallstrom's advice. But since you tagged this as Google Analytics and if you end up doing this yourself, inside your controller action you can send hits directly to Google Analytics using the [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/).

The flow would be:

1. Add the image to the email with pertinent data in the URL query string.
2. When the image request comes to your server, parse the query string for the appropriate data.
3. Send that data to Google Analytics via the Measurement Protocol.

Comment: Yes, once I figured out how to get it to the controller I was wondering about how to pipe it into Google Analytics if I wind up going that route. This is very helpful, thanks.